# Digital filtering in java Android is too slow

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, digital-filter

I am trying to **implement real-time digital filtering of audio signal in Android**. I used standard code for my high-pass filter:

```
void doFilter(final short in[], short out[], int sizeIn) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeIn; i++) {
        out[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if (i >= j) out[i] += H[j] * in[i - j];
            else out[i] += H[j] * dataTail[i + size - j];
    }
    System.arraycopy(in, sizeIn - size - 1, dataTail, 0, size);
}
```

The problem is that this **code works very slowly** to filter the signal from the microphone in real time: `200ms` for a filter of `100 samples` and input data of a long `1700 samples`. What is the reason and what are the ways to solve this problem? **Advise, please complete library for fast signal filtering.** Thanks.

Comment: You could use a variable to compute the sum and assign to out[i] outside the second (inner) loop. But I am not sure if this alone would be helpful.

Comment: @h22 I did not quite understand how this can help

Comment: Array member out[i] access may be slower than a single variable access, and you are doing many times in a loop. I am not sure if Android Java compiler is smart enough to optimize this.

Comment: How fast would it need to be before it is in the acceptable range? What exactly is dataTail (I understand the concept, but it's use is an unknown in this context)? Are you operating on buffers in a buffer queue? If not, why not? Are you absolutely sure this convolution is the bottleneck? If you do not perform the convolution, everything works as expected? This algorithm can be made faster, but only to a certain extent. If you are very far away from your goal and there are no other options for improvement, hotpaw2 may be right that you have to switch gears.

Comment: @Dave 40 ms is max acceptable range. DataTail is the tail of the previous data buffer. It is needed for continuity of input data.
I'm already fully convinced that Java is not suitable for solving my problem and now I'm looking for a ready JNI library.

Comment: You have data in Java and want to operate on it in native code. One little piece of advice is to be sure you use direct `ByteBuffer`s and be careful with your treatment of them in the JNI layer. Dragging data back and forth through JNI could impact performance more than a nested loop. I honestly think 5x improvement is achievable in just Java, unless you plan on doing more complex operations. I will try to put together an improved algorithm given your current code so you can compare, but I won't be able to get around to it for a day or two.

Comment: @Dave Ok, thank you, I'll wait.
At the moment I'm trying to use the Superpowered library for my purposes.

Comment: @SolderingIronMen I would like to ask some more questions, but it's probably better to move it to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153235/audio-filtering-in-java-android).

Answer (score 1):

Java is very slow for large number of calculations as compared to C/C++, Consider using Android NDK for JNI to compile your main logic in C/C++.

Comment: I'm new to JNI. What ready-made libraries can you advise for filtering signals?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done any sort of signals filtering. If you know basic C programming, it is really easy to implement simple functions like the one you posted in the question. Search for libraries in google, if you can't find them, Learn Android JNI.

Answer (score 1):

For a length 100 FIR filter kernel, you will likely need to use a zero-padded FFT/IFFT overlap add/save fast convolution method, instead of a time domain convolution.  This would be better written in C inside a JNI.  I don't know of a library, but the algorithms might be explained inside some DSP textbooks.